# System.NullPointerException

Tags: apex, soap, php

while making a call from php i am getting the error

> Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.Demo.Insert:

What is problem in my webservice?

```
global class Ctest{
    global class RequestClass{
        webservice String accName;
    }

    webservice static void   cInsert(RequestClass req){
        Account a1 = new Account();
        a1.Name = req.accName;
        insert a1;
    }
}
```

And Our Php Code Is

```
require_once('salesforceAPI/soapclient/SforceEnterpriseClient.php');
require_once('salesforceAPI/soapclient/SforceHeaderOptions.php');

$sfdc = new SforceEnterpriseClient();
$SoapClient = $sfdc->createConnection('enterprise.wsdl.xml');

$loginResult = false;

$loginResult = $sfdc->login(USER, PASSWORD . SECURITY_KEY);

$parsedURL = parse_url($sfdc->getLocation());
define("_SFDC_SERVER_", substr($parsedURL['host'], 0, strpos($parsedURL['host'], '.')));
define("_WS_NAME_", 'salesforceAPI/Ctest');
define("_WS_WSDL_", _WS_NAME_ . '.xml');
define("_WS_ENDPOINT_", 'https://' . _SFDC_SERVER_ . '.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/' . _WS_NAME_);
define("_WS_NAMESPACE_", 'http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/' . _WS_NAME_);

$client = new SoapClient(_WS_WSDL_);
$sforce_header = new SoapHeader(_WS_NAMESPACE_, "SessionHeader", array("sessionId" => $sfdc->getSessionId()));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($sforce_header));

$method = $client->__getFunctions();

$wsParams = array('accName' => 'XXXXXXX');

$client->cInsert($wsParams)
```

Comment: Based on the error message your `RequestClass` object passed into the `insert` method is `null`.

Without more detail on how you are invoking your webservice it's hard to give a more detailed answer.

Comment: @adtennant what i have to do modifications in my webservice'

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your webservice as it stands. There is a problem with how you are invoking it from PHP which is causing a `null` argument to be passed. If you add the PHP which you are using to invoke the webservice to your question that would help.

Comment: @adtennant webservice static void   insert(String accName) without using RequestClass it is working, when i use RequestClass at that time it is not working can you give me some suggestions.

Comment: Without seeing your PHP call I can't help you. There is not enough information in your question to answer it.

Comment: @adtennant the php code which we are using i post in the question Space,can you check it once.

Comment: I can't see anything immediately wrong with it, have you refreshed the WSDL? Can you try changing `$client->cInsert($wsParams)` to `$response = $client->cInsert($wsParams);
echo "<p><pre>" . print_r($response, true) . "</pre></p>";` and see what output you get.

Comment: @adtennant Ooop! Error: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Class.Ctest.cInsert:line 8 that means error occuring point   a1.Name = req.accName;

Comment: @adtennant Again we are getting the same error..

Comment: @adtennant Can you help me how to resolve the nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 2):

I know this may be a little late, but for all those 'googling' and reaching this page. The way you solve this issue is to create an Object with the parameters that are required from the WSDL. For example, say `accName` was required and it was of `type` `ID` then you would create an Object and pass the object into the SOAP function:

```
$object->accName = 'XXXXXX';
$object->type = 'ID';
$client->cInsert($object);
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in WS is that you don't check req variable for null. I would check req variable before using it.
If you will ask why it may be null - I don't know. I assume that you don't pass this param into WS. How to pass it in PHP - I don't know. I'm not good in PHP.

Comment: I want set my req variable to null..??

Comment: If it's a question - I don't know. If you're asking 'why' - I don't know either. Can you please rephrase your question/statement?

Comment: i have to check req variable for null in my webservice..

Comment: Yes, you should do it to prevent NullPointerException. But I suggest you to work on your PHP code to prevent nulls in WS' parameter. Or process null parameter somehow if you are expecting nulls.

Comment: May i know where i have to change my code.

Comment: I don't think that is his issue.  He simply isn't sending the correct type and so SFDC translates it as null.

Comment: @dphil, I don't know what he is sending. I know how to prevent NullPointerException in sfdc side. I'm not a PHP expert.

Comment: Same here.  I tried looking at the PHP to see what he did wrong, but I honestly don't understand it besides in rudimentary terms.

Comment: He puts array as param, but waits for a string. Maybe this is the problem.

Comment: I think the issue is that the array, is essentially a list of strings being passed into the service, and it is requesting an object.

Comment: Yes, I totally agree.